# Understanding how the override works with compareTo in a Java priority queue?

Tags: java, compare, heapsort

I'm making a custom priority queue where I essentially push objects to a PQ and sort by a specific key in that object:

## Priority Queue Entry Class

```
package Graphs;

public class PQEntry implements Comparable<PQEntry> {
    public int node;
    public int nodeVal;

    public PQEntry(int node, int nodeVal) {
        this.node = node;
        this.nodeVal = nodeVal;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Node: " + this.node + ", Value: " + this.nodeVal;
    }

    public int getNodeVal() {
        return this.nodeVal;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(PQEntry other) {
        return Integer.compare(this.getNodeVal(), other.nodeVal);
    }
}
```

Now, everything is fine and dandy, the priority works as it should:

```
PriorityQueue<PQEntry> pq = new PriorityQueue();
```

But I am new to Java and I am confused as to how/where/when the compareTo in my PQEntry class gets applied to the PriorityQueue class and how this is exactly working.

When I call the `add` function inside `PriorityQueue` does it initiate some swapping algorithm calling a super method from my PQEntry class? I'm really a bit new to Java and trying to understand the process flow here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to clarify things for you.

In the [documentation of PriorityQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) you'll notice it states:

> The elements of the priority queue are ordered according to their natural ordering, or by a Comparator provided at queue construction time, depending on which constructor is used. A priority queue does not permit null elements. A priority queue relying on natural ordering also does not permit insertion of non-comparable objects (doing so may result in ClassCastException).

The `PriorityQueue` expects either a `Comparator` or `Comparable` objects. As long as one of these is provided the queue will "work as it should" because it simply relies on those interfaces.

When a comparator is not provided `PriorityQueue` will try to cast elements as `Comparable` and then use the `compareTo` method to determine how to sort them.

When a comparator is provided `PriorityQueue` will simply use that object to perform the comparison of elements and sort them accordingly.

For further reading you can look at the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/), in particular the [lesson on Interfaces and Inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/index.html).